# qualitative research participants name

Tags: research-process

Basically, I am trying to find out the technical term for the participant in qualitative research, when the person giving the information is not the person experiencing the phenomena talked about first hand. So for example, I might ask a lawyer to talk about psychological impacts of the asylum seeking process, instead of asking people that have gone through the asylum seeking process themselves. This is done for reasons due to ethical concerns and also because the secondary source might be useful due to their vast amount of accumulated knowledge.

I know that the term exists, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll be doing interviews. If this is the case I would call them respondents